# Crispy Forms template not found

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have this code

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy form %}
```

That is throwing this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /student_update/13
foundation/field.html
```

I have these two apps installed:

```
'crispy_forms',
'crispy_forms_foundation'
```

This does not happen when developing locally on my computer, only when it's deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just run into this issue. You have to be explicit what foundation you are using, 3 or 5. In your settings, change (you likely have this):

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'foundation'
```

for one of these two:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'foundation-5'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'foundation-3'
```